# Updating Google Sheet with WooCommerce Order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to be able to automatically update a google sheet file every time an order is placed through WooCommerce.

I've found the solution below, but using this each individual item ordered is listed as a new row. I'd like the order to be grouped under the order number and the item quantities separated into appropriate columns instead.

https://www.tychesoftwares.com/export-woocommerce-orders-to-google-sheets-in-realtime/

Below is a Google Sheet we are manually updating at present to show you what i mean.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI2Lu.png)

Is there a way to send the WooCommerce orders directly through to Google Sheets in this format?

Thanks so much in advance for any advice!

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions, it will help you get the answers you are looking for and make the site better as a source of reference for future users. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes it looks possible.

I know nothing about WooCommerce, but I believe you can sort out the received data in any way you want.

Look, the last line in their script appends the received data as a new row:

```
sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_number,order_created,order_status]);
```

As far as I can see, the data contains the four elements:

- timestamp
- order_number
- order_created
- orders_status

Instead, you can put these elements into any cell on your table. Something like this, for example:

```
var ss = Spreadsheet.GetActiveSheet();
ss.getRange('A10').setValue(timestamp);                    // timestamp goes to A10
ss.getRange('B20').setValue(order_number);                 // order_number goes to B20
ss.getRange('C30').setValue(order_created + order_status); // created + status go to C30
```

The same way you can add any of these elements to some existing value in some cell, etc. For example:

```
var old_value = ss.getRange('A2').getValue(); // get value from the cell A2
var new_value = old_value + order_number;     // add with order_number
ss.getRange('A2').setValue(new_value);        // put the sum back into the cell A2
```

The main problem is up to you. You have to figure out:

- what exactly the elements you're receiving (number, names)
- how exactly you want to sort them out (what to add to what... what to put where... etc)

I can't understand it from the example picture.

#### Here is some reference documentation on Apps Script:

- [Main Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) - Introducing Apps Script.
- [Sheets Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) - Introduction to Sheets with Apps Script.
- [Sheets Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) - Where you will find all the details of everything you can do with Sheets in Apps Script.
- [Remove Duplicate Rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) - A good small tutorial that will teach you the basics of Sheets and Ranges and how to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

To export all my WooCommerce orders on a scheduled basis, I used a ready-made solution.
I used a WooCommerce API and JSON client. It worked smoothly: I got the WooCommerce API, and the JSON client was implemented in the tool already.

You just need to choose **endpoint** in the JSON client to get the required data.  I exported all orders once a month, so I used the base URL http:// mydomain /wp-json/wc/v3/**orders** and my **endpoint** was **orders**.

You can check [this article](https://blog.coupler.io/woocommerce-to-google-sheets/) to understand better how it works for your purpose.
And here is [WooCommerce API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/).

I assume that setting up an export through the Apps Script is more flexible (and based on the answer above, it's working indeed), but I'm not a code guy. So I searched for an easier solution, and the API + JSON client helped.

Hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using [WooCommerce Google Sheet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-gsheetconnector/) Plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30641243)